# Does omxplayer save a rtmp stream output by default?

Tags: omxplayer

I am watching a rtmp stream using omxplayer, but I was wondering if omxplayer saves some output of the stream by default?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

omxplayer does not save a RTMP stream to a file by default.

Use a tool like rtmpdump to actually do this.

```
sudo apt-get install rtmpdump
rtmpdump -r rtmp://example.com/path/to/video -o downloaded_file.mp4
```